# Laravel 5.5 and Angular 4 set cookie

Tags: php, angular, cookies, laravel-5, homestead

I used laravel as backend (that implemented at homestead - mydomain.test) and angular 4 as frontend (that implemented at http://localhost:4200), now, I want to set a cookie from backend to frontend browser.

Backend Controller:

```
return response(['access_token'=>$response['access_token'], 'expires_in' => $response['expires_in']])
          ->withCookie($cookie);
```

and response is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sat, 30 Dec 2017 09:01:11 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.9
Set-Cookie:refreshToken=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; expires=Thu, 22-Aug-2019 09:01:11 GMT; Max-Age=51840000; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-RateLimit-Limit:60
X-RateLimit-Remaining:59
```

but when I want to send the cookie from frontend to backend , it does not work! I used angular 4:

```
refreshToken(){

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()})
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

return this.http.post(API_DOMAIN + 'refresh', JSON.stringify({}), options)
  .map(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
      return response.json()
    },
  )
}
```

and backend side:

```
$refreshToken = $request->cookie(self::REFRESH_TOKEN);
var_dump($refreshToken); // to be null always
```

Can you help me to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by:
Create proxy.conf.json in the root of Angular app. Put an object with routes inside:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://mydomian.test/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I just have /api defined here because all my backend URIs are inside api.php. All calls that look like http://localhost:4200/api/someitems/1 will be proxied to http://mydomian.test/api/someitems/1. 
Then edit package.json and change the value of start inside scripts to ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json. Now npm run start will start with proxy. The problem I had with this proxy is that it resolves your URL (http://mydomian.test/) to an IP. When it calls Laravel with just an IP the nginx server does not know what to do because it must receive a domain name. nginx allows multiple website on the same IP so it must receive a domain name or to have a default website to which it redirects all calls those have no domain name. In case this is still not fixed in Angular's proxy go to /etc/nginx/sites-available on the Laravel machine, you'll have a mydomian.test config file there. It has listen 80; line there, change it to listen 80 default;.

Now you can change the API_DOMAIN variable to http://localhost:4200 (or remove it all together) and disable the CORS.