# Angular: Laravel 5.6 session cookie not set in browser

Tags: php, angular, laravel, session, cookies

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and Angular 6. My backend uses the standard session login precedure of Laravel, but there is a problem:

In **Postman-Tests** everything works - I get a `Set-Cookie` header from Laravel and I'm authenticated. If I open my API in the **browser manually**, I get the `Set-Cookie` header from Laravel, the cookie get stored in the browser and I'm authenticated - everything fine. But if I'm trying to access the API from my **Angular-App**, then the cookie is not set in the browser - although there is the correct `Set-Cookie` header.

Can anyone help me? The App is delivert from `localhost:4200` and the API from `localhost:4100`. Is that a problem?

Comment: the [`api` middleware in laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L29) does not read cookies by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is probably do to your Angular app trying to access the cookie

> All cookies created by the Laravel framework are encrypted and signed
>   with an authentication code, meaning they will be considered invalid
>   if they have been changed by the client.

Apparently using Angular with Laravel is not straightforward there is a guide to how to integrate it here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

These might be related to your problem:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5254

[angular 4 not send cookie to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058193/angular-4-not-send-cookie-to-server?rq=1)

[Laravel 5.5 and Angular 4 set cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032470/laravel-5-5-and-angular-4-set-cookie)

Comment: @SebastianS no problem, glad you found the solution! If you found my answer useful I would appreciate it if you upvoted it ;)